# How to Update using a Co-Related subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

***Note***: This is NOT homework. I have simplified my situation into generic tables.

So I have two tables. Table 1 and Table2.
the VALUE1 in table1 is what I want to set.
Calculated as **VALUE1 = Apples(VALUE2)-Oranges(VALUE3)**

```
TABLE1
ID          INT //PRIMARY KEY
VALUE1      INT
VALUE2      INT //FOREIGN KEY TO TABLE2
VALUE3      INT //FOREIGN KEY TO TABLE2
```

.

```
TABLE2
ID          INT //PRIMARY KEY
APPLES      INT
ORANGES     INT
```

.

Which brings me to the question. How to Update using a Co-Related subquery?

Here is what I tried,
It executes without errors but the value remains unchanged. Which I find strange.

```
UPDATE TABLE1 AS X 
SET VALUE1= 
(SELECT APPLES FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID = X.VALUE2)
-
(SELECT ORANGES FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID = X.VALUE3) 
WHERE X.ID=12;
```

Comment: Try to give an alias to TABLE2  in subquery and use it for ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` instead of correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 AS x
JOIN TABLE2 AS y1 ON y1.id = x.value2
JOIN TABLE2 AS y2 ON y2.id = x.value3
SET value1 = y1.apples = y2.oranges
WHERE x.id = 12
```

Comment: Wouldn't JOIN be more costly on memory at large number of rows? Just curious?

Comment: No, it's essentially the same. It should first filter `table1` using the `WHERE` clause, then join just the rows that match.

Comment: I think you mean apples - oranges